# HTML5-related dialect compatible with Thymeleaf 3?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, dialect

While developping with Thymeleaf, I spotted the [HTML5 Validation Dialect](http://html5valdialect.sourceforge.net/) under the [*Community Dialects* at the Thymeleaf website](http://www.thymeleaf.org/ecosystem.html).

But now I'm currently integrating it, I found out this dialect is unfortunately not compatible with Thymeleaf 3 because it extends `org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractXHTMLEnabledDialect` which can't be found anymore in `thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar`

Indeed, someone requested support on 2016-09-22: https://sourceforge.net/p/html5valdialect/tickets/11/

Otherwise, I spotted someone who forked the dialect, but to no avail (because despite some `pom.xml` dependency updates, it stills extends that `AbstractXHTMLEnabledDialect` class)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758466/666414

Does anyone has a hint to something alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I forked the "Thymeleaf Html 5valdialect",
and updated it to support Thymeleaf 3.

Please take a look.

https://github.com/masa-kunikata/html5valdialect